# Ansible include_vars: Including dictionary variables from a file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to load dictionary variables from a file and can't access the variables inside. Could you please help me? sorry for so simple a question

Here is a working code example:

```
---
  tasks:
  - name: Dict test
    vars:
      users:
        alice:
          name: Alice Appleworth
          telephone: 123-456-7890
        bob:
          name: Bob Bananarama
          telephone: 987-654-3210
    debug:
      msg: "User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', users) }}"
```

But when I add the dict to a file and use include_vars to load it, the above code doesn't work.

File: test1.yml

```
users:
  alice:
    name: Alice Appleworth
    telephone: 123-456-7890
  bob:
    name: Bob Bananarama
    telephone: 987-654-3210
```

The following code doesn't work

```
  tasks:
  - name: Dict test
    include_vars: test1.yml
    debug:
      msg: "User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', users) }}"
```

But ansible dubuging -vvv shows

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "users": [
            {
                "alice": null,
                "name": "Alice Appleworth",
                "telephone": "123-456-7890"
            },
            {
                "bob": null,
                "name": "Bob Bananarama",
                "telephone": "987-654-3210"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Generally "does not work" is meaningless by itself -- you should cite the error-message(s) you're getting...

Answer (score 2):

"Doesn't work" is a very vague description of your problem, but this is not a valid task definition:

```
  - name: Dict test
    include_vars: test1.yml
    debug:
      msg: "User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', users) }}"
```

`include_vars` and `debug` are individual actions so they need to be separate tasks; as you have it this should give you the helpful error `ERROR! conflicting action statements: include_vars, debug`

```
  - include_vars: test1.yml

  - name: Dict test
    debug:
      msg: "User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
    loop: "{{ users | dict2items }}"
```